# Knitr-error from Task Schedule Manager

Tags: r, batch-file, knitr

I am trying to set up a task that runs a batch-file, that runs a `.rmd` file which should **knitr** me a lovely `.html` file each day.

Everything works fine, if I run the batch-file manually. However, when I run it through the task scheduler, I get the following error from the command prompt:

```
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> -> knit -> writeLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file<con, "w") : cannot open file 'residual_v1.md" : Permission denied
Execution halted
```

The same user is listed as the "author" in the task-scheduler, as the user when you open the start menu.

Batch-file code:

```
"C:\R\R-3.0.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" -e "library(knitr,dplyr); knitr::knit2html('C:/R/Rapporter/residual_model/Residual_v1.Rmd')"
```

Im am at a loss of what to do.

Comment: Have you tried running some code that doesn't produce a file? Scheduler works for me when I write to a (txt) file.

Comment: Yes, I can run & write .csv files without any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks you do not have write permission in the working directory of R. I'd recommend you to set the working directory before you run `knit2html()`, e.g.

```
setwd('C:/R/Rapporter/residual_model/')
knitr::knit2html('Residual_v1.Rmd')
```

i.e.

```
"C:\R\R-3.0.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" -e "setwd('C:/R/Rapporter/residual_model/'); knitr::knit2html('Residual_v1.Rmd')"
```

Or any other output directory in which you have write permission:

```
setwd('any/output/directory/you/want')
knitr::knit2html('C:/R/Rapporter/residual_model/Residual_v1.Rmd')
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding this: `setwd('C:/R/Rapporter/residual_model/');` to my batch-file solved the problem.